# Biopython translation script not working?

Tags: python, translation, sequence, biopython

I'm new to Biopython and I simply want to translate a DNA Fasta file and write the output to a new file. I thought it would be easy but I can't get the script to work.
Here is my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

in = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
out = open(sys.argv[2],'w')

messenger_rna = Seq(in, IUPAC.unambiguous_rna)
out = messenger_rna.translate()

out.close()
in.close()
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What are you seeing that you aren't expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know what all this [biopython](/questions/tagged/biopython) etc. is, I am quite sure that you treat the files wrong.

Especially

```
out = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
out = messenger_rna.translate()
out.close()
```

seems wrong to me.

Replace the middle line with

```
out.write(messenger_rna.translate())
```

if that is a string what `.translate()` returns.

Further optimized version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as infile: # for auto-closing
    messenger_rna = Seq(infile, IUPAC.unambiguous_rna)
    # if Seq() takes a string rather than a file, do infile.read() instead.

with open(sys.argv[2],'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(messenger_rna.translate())
```

Comment: Yes, Glglgl is right. Your original code opens an output handle and stores this as 'out', then creates a translated sequence and ASSIGNS this to the 'out' variable (should be calling the output handle's write method). This drops any reference to the output handle, it will be closed automatically. Finally you tell the translated sequence to close - which fails.

Comment: @user1882385 A thanks is best expressed on SO by accepting the most helpful answer by clicking on the ckeck mark. :-)